# TeamCity VisualStudio build step isn't finding all the packages.config files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm running into a build issue in TeamCity with a "Visual Studio (sln)" build step where most but not all of the nuget packages are downloaded.

The following error is reported which on further inspection is caused by a missing NuGet package.

```
[Tests.cs(10, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)]
```

I found that the offending project didn't have its packages.config file listed in repositories.config so I added it. This didn't correct the issue so I added a "NuGet Installer" step before the build.

The Nuget Installer step uses looks at repositories.config file so now my project builds. That said I still don't understand why the Visual Studio build-step that downloads so many NuGet packages misses these ones.

It's able to identify the required package and download it without issue when I build with VisualStudio.

Is there an equivalent or repositories.config that is used by visualStudio 2015?

Why would a TeamCity "Visual Studio (sln)" build step fail to use a packages.config file that VisualStudio 2015 does?

Thank you

Comment: Please share your build step configuration for Teamcity to help us reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent or repositories.config that is used by
>   visualStudio 2015?

In Visual Studio 2015, the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio extension will find all packages.config files under solution when restore NuGet packages. And it will download the packages from the package sources that configured in NuGet.Config which stored in path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

Following TeamCity "Visual Studio (sln)" build step doesn't use repositories.config and also doesn't need Nuget Installer step. Please make sure all the **packages.config files are all checked in** to your source control with your solution. I'm using **TeamCity 10.0.3**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do a nuget install before hand, and in the package sources i specifiy my repository. e.g.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJLnX.png)